# Updating to Wakanda 11: "[Backend] Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in undefined on line undefined"

Tags: wakanda

I am looking to move my Wakanda application, created in Enterprise Studio v10, to Enterprise Studio/Server v11. I can start the solution successfully, but when I try to view my webapp in browsers, Wakanda Studio logs the error:

> [Backend] Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in undefined on line undefined

and the browser shows just a white page with some console errors (below).

Edit: commenting out all occurrences of `.replace()` does not solve the problem. I do not believe it is possible that this issue is the result of `.replace()` statements that I've written.

I do use `string.replace()` with regular expressions in a few places. The code works perfectly fine in v10 and am confused about what could be wrong.

Here is an example of how I am using `replace()` in the code:

```html
var tempString = "";
tempString = tempEntity.sourceProjects;
tempString = tempString.replace(/,/g, " ");
tempString = tempString.replace(/other_/, "Other: ");
```

The code was more streamlined before- I broke it out into pieces in an attempt to get rid of the error, but no dice.

Browser with console errors:
[image: Browser errors]

What I see when I click on "Loader.js: 2073"

[image: loader.js:2073]

Comment: what do you see at line 2157 of loader.js

Comment: [![loader.js:2157][1]][1]
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9g2Ug.png

Comment: Hi Tim, I solved this today. I deleted my index.package.json file in my index.waPage, and let Wakanda v11 regenerate it. The site works fine now.

The old index.package.json file works fine in v10.

This had nothing to do with code I had written.

Comment: very interesting, thanks for the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Quit Wakanda
2) Delete the old [`index.package.json`](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Architecture-of-Wakanda-Applications/Page-Prototype.200-1022685.en.html) file inside of `index.waPage`
3) Restart Wakanda and let Wakanda v11 regenerate it

Comment: Thank you- I changed all occurrences of `.replace()` to be conditionally executed on `tempString` only when `tempString.length > 0`. However, this did not solve my issue. The block of code I cited is now exactly like you have it.

Comment: What is in tempEntity.sourceProjects and what is at line 2157 of loader.js

Comment: `tempEntity.sourceProjects` is a string; I get tempEntity from a datastore query: 

`var pieceCollection = ds.DataRequestTemp.query("username = :1", mySession.user.name);`

Then I navigate through every returned Entity in the Entity Collection via:

`pieceCollection.forEach(
  function (tempEntity) {`

Also, line 2157: i.stack.imgur.com/9g2Ug.png

Answer (score 0):

You have the error :  "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" because in line 2, tempEntity is an empty string and  you write tempEntity.sourceProjects.

The value of tempEntity.sourceProjects is "undefined", so when you try to use replace in line 3 you get this error.

Issam

Comment: Thank you, this was a good idea but the problem was with my index.waPage index.package.json file. I found this by deleting it and allowing Wakanda Studio v11 to regenerate it. The site works fine in v11 now. The old index.package.json file is running fine in v10 so I'm not sure why v11 did not tolerate it.